# user input to a Char Array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that takes a user's answer for a test and puts it in a char array, and then compares it to an array with the answers. 
I have a problem with input the user's Answers into the char array. I keep getting an EE saying that in.nextLine(); - there is no line found and it throws a no such element exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class driverExam {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Driver's Test. Input your answers for the following 
10 Q's. ");
    System.out.println();

    char[] testAnswers = {'B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D'};
    int uA =9;
    String userInput;


    for (int i =0; i<uA;i++) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Question #"+(i+1)+": ");
            userInput = in.nextLine();
            in.close();

            int len = userInput.length();
            char[] userAnswers = new char [len];
            for(int x =0;x<len;x++) {
            userAnswers[i] = userInput.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println(userAnswers);
        }
    System.out.println("Your answers have been recorded.");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only close the resource once you're completely done with it. (Not within the loop) That being said don't close the `Scanner`. It is bad practice to close `System.in`. The general rule is that if you didn't open it, you shouldn't close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't userAnswers array be of size 10? 
Your program has quite redundant and unnecessary steps, according to me. So I have modified it to meet your need. 
There is no need to put the "Scanner in...." inside the loop.

This loop is full of mistakes. Not discouraging, just saying.

```
     for (int i =0; i<uA;i++) 
     {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//scanner inside loop
        System.out.print("Question #"+(i+1)+": ");
        userInput = in.nextLine();
        in.close();//already mentioned by someone in the comment
        int len = userInput.length();
        char[] userAnswers = new char [len];//no need to declare array inside loop
        for(int x =0;x<len;x++) 
        {
           userAnswers[i] = userInput.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
        }
  }

    System.out.println(userAnswers);//this will not print the array,it will print 
    //something like [I@8428 ,[ denotes 1D array,I integer,and the rest of it has 
     //some meaning too
```

Now here is the code which will get  the work done

```
char[] testAnswers = {'B','D','A','A','C','A','B','A','C','D'};
int uA =testAnswers.length;//to find the length of testAnswers array i.e. 10
char[] userAnswers = new char [uA]; 
char userInput;
int i;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (i =0; i<uA;i++) 
 {           
        System.out.print("Question #"+(i+1)+": ");
        userInput = Character.toUpperCase(in.next().charAt(0));
 }

  for(i=0;i<ua;i++) 
  {
       System.out.println(userAnswers[i]);
  }
  System.out.println("Data has been recorded");
```

I am not demeaning, just trying to help.